# Compare where two vectors are the same value

Tags: matlab, vector, confusion-matrix

I'd like to create a confusion matrix in matlab. To do this, I need to calculate, for example, true positives and true negatives.

In order to do this I need to go through each vector element-wise comparing true values in one vector to true values in the other. If they both equal the true value at the same index, then I can increment true positives. I can do the same for the negative value to calculate true negatives.

However, the only way I can think of doing this is with for loop. It will work fine, but since matlab is vectorized there has to be a better way to do this that doesn't involve using a for loop.

What is the best way to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of the accuracy of my answer to your real-world problem, but here goes. If your two vectors of actual and predicted values are, say, `A` and `P` then you can compute the number of true positives and negatives as:

```
truePositiveCount = sum( A & P );
trueNegativeCount = sum( ~A & ~P );
```